# Image of an Open Disk Given Function

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Say I am given a function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, where $f(z) = z^n$ for $n \geq 1$ is a positive integer, and given a disk $D(0, \varepsilon) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon\}$, and I want to find the image of $f$ under $D(0, \varepsilon)$, i.e. I find $f(D(0, \varepsilon))$. So by definition of the image of a function, I have
\begin{align*}
f(D(0, \varepsilon)) &= \{f(z) \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)| < \varepsilon\} \tag{*} \\
&= \{z^n \in \mathbb{C} : |z^n| < \varepsilon\} \\
&= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|^n < \varepsilon\}
\end{align*}
Now I consider cases where $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd. If even then
\begin{equation*}
f(D(0, \varepsilon)) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z| < \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon}\}
\end{equation*}
and when $n$ is odd,
\begin{equation*}
f(D(0, \varepsilon)) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon}\}
\end{equation*}

Would this be the correct way of finding the image under a disk? In particular where I labelled (*)?

Comment: Regarding language: "... the image of $f$ under $D(0, \varepsilon)$" is backwards. We speak of "the image of <subset of domain> under <function>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be

$$\begin{align*}
f(D(0, \varepsilon)) &= \{f(z) \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon\}    \\
&= \{z^n \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon\} \\
&= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon^n\}
\end{align*}$$

What you found is the pre-image of $D(0, \varepsilon)$, that is, the set of points that map to $D(0, \varepsilon)$ by $f$.

Comment: Just curious how you would translate from $\{z^n \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon\}$ to just $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < \varepsilon^n\}$. is it because that $f(\varepsilon) = \varepsilon^n$, so that would cause $|z| < f(z)$? I am not sure about this.

Comment: If $|z|<\varepsilon$, then $|f(z)|=|z^n|=|z|\cdots|z|<\varepsilon^n$. To see the other inclusion, take $w$ such that $|w|<\varepsilon^n$ and $\text{arg}(w)=\alpha$. Then, defining $z$ as the complex number with norm $\sqrt[n]{|w|}$ and argument $\alpha/n$ we have that $z^n=w$ and $|z|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: So wouldn't the last line be $|z|^n < \varepsilon^n$ instead, or that wouldn't really change?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent to $|z|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification!